# Asus M32 desktop motherboard will not power on. Unknown purpose of its "VRM_BOOT" pins

Tags: boot, motherboard, desktop-computer, diagnostic, voltage

My Asus M32 desktop will not power on after a power outage. The CPU fan does not spin and there is no video output when the power button is pressed. I've used 4 different power supplies to try to get a startup; one of the power supplies had an LED that turned on when plugged in, the fans of the other power supplies did not run, and the power supply that was used in the outage is being used in another machine (its still functional). I've tested the CPU and storage devices with another motherboard and they all work fine. I did not notice any physical damage to the board. I've noticed two connectors next to the CPU fan connector (from left to right): VRM_BOOT_SW103 and VRM_BOOT_SW102. Each have a two pin header. Are there any other boards with these headers? If so, could adding a jumper to one or both of these headers have a significant impact on powering up the board?

- Motherboard model: H110-M/M32CD/DP_MB (the only manual I can find is the [user guide](https://static.bhphotovideo.com/lit_files/143117.pdf), which just illustates how to plug in your keyboard, mouse, and monitor)
- CPU: Intel® Core™ i5-6400 Processor

[Updated image of VRM_BOOT headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFhvd.jpg)

**Update: Problem is not resolved, still looking for solutions**

Comment: Your picture is so out of focus it really isn't helpful.  Manual for the motherboard should tell you something about the VRM_BOOT header.  What makes you think the reason your PC won't even attempt to turn on is because of this header?

Comment: @Ramhound The motherboard is from a retail machine, it only came with a user guide with no details on any kinds of connections that are inside the case.

Comment: VRM_Boot stands for `Voltage Regulation Modules Boot`

Comment: @Ramhound I've updated the picture and could not find any other boards with those headers. I would like to read the manual of a board that has these to understand the significance of them.

Comment: I have been able to find them.  Hence the reason I know what the VRM stands for.  I won't be performing a lecture on what a Voltage Regulation Module switch does on a motherboard, entire college programs are dedicated to that.

Comment: @Ramhound could you leave me with some model names as an example?

Comment: I found them in a google search, I found what I was looking for, what VRM stood for.  I didn't keep the google search result because it served no purpose.  https://www.google.com/#safe=off&q=Voltage+Regulation+Modules helps you understand what these modules are used for though.

Comment: You don't want to add a "jumper" to those switches.  You are looking down the wrong rabbit hole.  [Here[(https://www.google.com/#safe=off&q=asus+VRM) is the other google search I found.  All motherboards have a VRM, what they are labeled on the motherboard, depends on various design factors

Comment: @Ramhound I am looking for more information about the headers themselves. I've been searching for images of motherboards and could not find any with these headers. I am looking for a specific motherboard that features these so I can read its manual and find jumper configuration.

Comment: You do understand the VRMs do not have jumpers, they are not pins, connecting the two posts will be very bad.

Comment: @Ramhound The computer was so cheaply put together that I had suspected the VRMs had to be configured manually with jumpers, maybe not. Thanks for the help.

Comment: An power outage will not magically change jumpers. If it worked before then the all the jumpers were in the right place. (And that is assuming that they are jumpers and not measuring points.)

Comment: @Hennee those posts are not jumpers, connecting them would be bad.

Comment: Look for lights. Asus has error lights. Look up manual. since you're switching PSUs check to see if the 6-8 pin connector next to the cpu is plugged in

Comment: @Journeyman Geek♦ The board was cheaply made. I could not find any LED indicators on the board and the front panel power button does not illuminate since the outage. The only manual I could find for the board was the user guide. I've checked the pin connector for the CPU and it was connected properly.